# if (!document.images)

Tags: javascript

I have been using JavaScript tutorials to help me implement some JavaScript in my college assignment. I have therefore used one to help me create an image slideshow and it contains an if statement that looks like the one below.

```
if (!document.images)
    return
document.images.SlideShow1.src=eval("image"+slide+".src
```

However I am not quite sure what it is doing especially the `(!document.images)` part.

EDIT

Also as I can see that I have made a bad choice with this tutorial would anyone show me how to make a good image slideshow or simply direct me to a good tutorial? This is all of the code I am currently using

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var image1=new Image()
        image1.src="Images/Foam2012/Misty.gif"
        var image2=new Image()
        image2.src="Images/Foam2012/Foamy.gif"
        var image3=new Image()
        image3.src="Images/Foam2012/17.gif"
        var image4=new Image()
        image4.src="Images/Foam2012/16.gif"
        var image5=new Image()
        image5.src="Images/Foam2012/2.gif"
        var image6=new Image()
        image6.src="Images/Oxjam2012/Rainbow.gif"
        var image7=new Image()
        image7.src="Images/Oxjam2012/17.gif"
        var image8=new Image()
        image8.src="Images/Oxjam2012/9.gif"
        var image9=new Image()
        image9.src="Images/Oxjam2012/2.gif"
        var image10=new Image()
        image10.src="Images/RagDay2012/GasMask.gif"
        var image11=new Image()
        image11.src="Images/RagDay2012/22.gif"
        var image12=new Image()
        image12.src="Images/RagDay2012/21.gif"
        var image13=new Image()
        image13.src="Images/RagDay2012/20.gif"
        var image14=new Image()
        image14.src="Images/RagDay2012/16.gif"
        var image15=new Image()
        image15.src="Images/RagDay2012/6.gif"
        var image16=new Image()
        image16.src="Images/RagDay2012/5.gif"       
        var image17=new Image()
        image17.src="Images/RagDay2012/4.gif"
        var image18=new Image()
        image18.src="Images/RagDay2012/1.gif"
        var image19=new Image()
        image19.src="Images/UV2012/17.gif"
        var image20=new Image()
        image20.src="Images/UV2012/14.gif"
        var image21=new Image()
        image21.src="Images/UV2012/9.gif"
        var image22=new Image()
        image22.src="Images/UV2012/7.gif"
        var image23=new Image()
        image23.src="Images/UV2012/6.gif"
        //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="SlideShow1" style="padding-bottom: 5px" src="Images/Foam2012/Foamy.gif"      width="350px" height="300px" alt="Image Slideshow"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var slide = 1
        //Declares a variable called slide which equals 1
        function slideit(){
        if (!document.images)
        return
        document.images.SlideShow1.src=eval("image"+slide+".src")
        if (slide<23)
        slide++
        else
        slide = 1
        //call function "slideit()" every 1.5 seconds
        setTimeout("slideit()",1500)
        }
        slideit()
        //-->
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: document.images is a collection of all the images in the current document. The code is checking if there's images and if there's none then it simply returns.

Comment: It seems that this is pretty useless check. Because all modern browsers including IE6 support `images` propery of the `document` object. Even if there are no images on the page `document.images` will evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this tutorial down! It is (a) ancient...

```
if (!document.images)
   return
```

This is doing feature-sniffing for the `images` collection, an old-fashioned way of getting hold of `<img>` elements. Every JavaScript-capable browser since Netscape 3 has supported that array, so it reveals a script of 1996-odd vintage.

...and (b) terrible.

```
document.images.SlideShow1.src=eval("image"+slide+".src");
```

This is the mark of someone who really doesn't have a clue what they are doing. You have always been able to access object properties using `[]` syntax:

```
document.images.SlideShow1.src=window['image'+slide].src;
```

So there never was any need to use the slow, dangerous, awful method of creating a JavaScript expression in a string and `eval`ing it - even by 1996 standards, this is poor.

But even so, accessing variables by name off `window` is typically questionable.

ETA:

> would anyone show me how to make a good image slideshow

Well, I don't know about the best slideshow - I'm sure someone will step in to promote a favourite existing library, but we can certainly improve the code you've got as an example.

So holding a series of objects in separate numbered variables is generally a sign that what you really want is an array:

```
# List of image paths inside Images/
#
var paths= [
    'Foam2012/Misty.gif', 'Foam2012/Foamy.gif', 'Foam2012/17.gif', 'Foam2012/16.gif', 'Foam2012/2.gif',
    'Oxjam2012/Rainbow.gif', 'Oxjam2012/17.gif', 'Oxjam2012/9.gif', 'Oxjam2012/2.gif',
    'RagDay2012/GasMask.gif', 'RagDay2012/22.gif', 'RagDay2012/21.gif', 'RagDay2012/20.gif', 'RagDay2012/16.gif', 'RagDay2012/6.gif', 'RagDay2012/5.gif', 'RagDay2012/4.gif', 'RagDay2012/1.gif',
    'UV2012/17.gif', 'UV2012/14.gif', 'UV2012/9.gif', 'UV2012/7.gif', 'UV2012/6.gif',
];

# Preload images
#
var images= [];
for (var i= 0; i<paths.length; i++) {
    var image= new Image();
    image.src= 'Images/'+paths[i];
    images.push(image);
}

# Rotate image every 1.5s
#
var imagei= 0;
setInterval(function() {
    imagei= (imagei+1) % images.length;
    document.getElementById('SlideShow1').src= images[imagei].src;
}, 1500);
```

There are other things you could do to make this better - for example, it would probably be better to have all the images as `<img>` tags in the page so that their content is visible to non-JavaScript agents such as search engines. You could then show and hide them using the `display` CSS style.

> or simply direct me to a good tutorial?

[It's a problem](http://www.goer.org/Journal/2011/08/search_engines_and_js_tutorials_still_appalling.html). I haven't looked for a while but standards are typically poor.

Although I'm not a fan of jQuery, you might find some of the tutorial material that uses it helpful as at least it tends to be written in a more modern way.

Comment: is there any chance you could give me an example or direct me to a different tutorial that is up to date and works well?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Internet Explorer</strike> There may be a browser that doesn't have an "images" property on document objects, so that test just sees if the slide show is going to work. A test like:

```
if (!something.property_name)
```

in JavaScript is a (slightly risky, depending on circumstances) way to test whether an object has a property with a certain name. In this case it's not risky: if there's an "images" property on the document object, then it'll be a list (possibly empty) of the images (`<img>` DOM elements) in the document. If the property is not there, then that test will return `true`.

(*edit* — IE does have the property, though the documentation skips it.)

Consensus here is that it's not worthwhile to test for it.  I also think you might consider whether what you really want is a slideshow covering *all* the images on a page. Seems to me that that's not likely to be realistic; real pages have images for icons, headings, logos, widgets, etc.  There are better APIs for finding images of interest for purposes like yours.

Comment: IE doesn't have this array ? Do you have a source ? Or did you check it using IE (I don't have such a browser).

Comment: @dystroy I just looked on [the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'll check again.

Comment: Well I'm firing up my VM now :-)  It's not documented on the MSDN page that I linked above.

Comment: @duri et al - yes it does seem to be there in IE7, so I'll assume it's been there. Odd that it's left out of the documentation; usually that's fairly accurate (or at least it was until they cleaned it up recently and got rid of a whole bunch of stuff).

Comment: My opinion is that this test is wholly obsolete. It should be removed now.

Comment: @dystroy yes you're probably right.  (Actually I think that in practice, on any modern site, the `images` list is not very useful anyway, and something like `querySelectorAll()` is what you'd really use.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!document.images)
```

test if `images` exists in document (not null) because

- Different browser has different names for their attributes
- The page may have no image

For `document.images` it appear there is no reason to test the existence of the attribute : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_images.asp

Comment: Firefox still has a non-empty "images" property when there are no images.